# How to trigger method on last when going to page page in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am will open page 2 from page 1. I will edit some info on page 2, then use Navigation.PopAsync() and I want to trigger method on Page 1 to refresh page 1 data. How can I do that in xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the refresh on Page1 via triggering the `OnDisappearing` on Page2.

Page2:

```
 async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        //refresh(); 
    }
```

Comment: That's great way, thanks for showing me that, but `refresh()` is on page 1 and I need to trigger it from page 2.

Comment: Invoke the `refresh()` in the `OnDisappearing` method like invoke a method from another class. It works.